# Touch intercept in custom viewgroup

Tags: android

I'm following the example here:

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

What I'm finding though is that onTouchEvent gets called even if onInterceptTouchEvent returns false. That seems to directly contradict the comments on this example.

What's up here? What am I missing? Are there some properties of the child or viewGroup that must be satisfied for these comments to be true?

If I wanted this behavior, what's the best way to go about it?

Comment: post the code of your custom ViewGroup

Comment: This should explain things a bit: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29 was clearly the way to go - that tutorial is pretty deceiving, since it doesn't really work the way it's described unless the children meet a very specific set of criteria.

For instance, the onTouchEvents of the children must return true to keep intercepting events. Read the link to get the deets.